# How to auto-popup the alert when certain condition is met at the start of the Kivy application

Tags: python, kivy, popup

I am looking for some conditional alert() code which should run when the app starts e.g. if password is expired than it should auto popup the alert and close the app when user clicks on close button. I have written the code in python and kivy.
I have tried using the on_start() function but somehow not able to place a proper logic/code.

.py file:

```
def closeapp(self, arg):
    App.get_running_app().stop()
    Window.close()
          
def on_start(self):
        exp_date = "24/05/2021"
        past = datetime.strptime(exp_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
        present = datetime.now()
        if past.date() <= present.date():  
             print (" Password expired. ")
             self.popup.open()   
        else:
            pass
    
class MyLayout(TabbedPanel):
    ## Main code of the app is written in this section

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
            on_start(self)
            return MyLayout()
```

.kv file

```
<MyLayout>
    do_default_tab: False

    size_hint: 1, 1
    padding: 10
    tab_pos: 'top_left'
    
    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab1
##Afer this Main design code starts except the Popup code
```

I am not sure whether I should use separate .kv files for popup design or continue to use the same .kv file, in both the scenarios how to run the code automatically at the start of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_start` function must be defined in the main class of the application, then it works correctly. If you plan to make a large application, it is better to use a separate file `.kv`, so the syntax will also be highlighted.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
from datetime import datetime

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLayout>
    do_default_tab: False

    size_hint: 1, 1
    padding: 10
    tab_pos: 'top_left'
    
    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab1
        
<MyPopup>:
    title: 'Alert'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Text'
            
        Button:
            text: 'Close me!'
            on_release: 
                root.dismiss()
                app.close_app()
""")


class MyPopup(Popup):
    pass


class MyLayout(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popup = MyPopup()

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

    @staticmethod
    def close_app(*args):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

    def on_start(self):
        exp_date = "24/05/2021"
        past = datetime.strptime(exp_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
        present = datetime.now()
        if past.date() <= present.date():
            print(" Password expired. ")
            self.popup.open()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I have already done the entire coding in .py file and GUI in .kv file hence need your help to add conditional popup in the existing files. Changing the existing structure is not possible at this stage. Thanks.

Comment: I have provided a working example that satisfies your question, if you need the `kv` code to be in a separate file, just copy it there

Comment: Thanks for you reply again. I have made the changes in the .py file and in .kv file. but getting error i.e. 
**PopupException: Popup can have only one widget as content.** I thing it is conflicting with the existing code in .kv file.

Comment: '<MyLayout>
 do_default_tab: False
 size_hint: 1, 1
 padding: 10
 tab_pos: 'top_left'
    TabbedPanelItem:
     id: tab1
  text: "Nft"
<MyPopup>:
    title: 'Alert'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'text'

        Button:
            text: 'Close me!'
            on_release: 
                root.dismiss()
                app.close_app()
 BoxLayout:
     id:t1bl1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                id:t1h

Comment: Most likely, read carefully about [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html) and see my example above, if you can't solve the problem, attach a file with the code and comments here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The PopupException  is resolved